# Creating a MySQL view due to NULL Values

Tags: mysql

I try to setup the following VIEW and defined 3 cases that lead to a specified match between columns of 2 tables in the WHERE clause.

This works more or less, because the view has entries that should have been excluded due to my statement. Please see the screenshot with the select * output therefore.

Can you help me here? Many thanks beforehand.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `match` AS SELECT 
a.`werksnr`,
b.`werksnr` AS `werksnr_ref`, 
a.`EAN`,
b.`EAN` AS `EAN_ref`, 
a.`lieferant`,
b.`lieferant` AS `lieferant_ref`, 
a.`artikel`, 
b.`artikel` AS `artikel_ref`,  
a.`artikelbezeichnung` AS `bezeichnung_suspect`,
b.`artikelbezeichnung1`, 
b.`artikelbezeichnung2`

FROM suspect as a, reference as b WHERE 

(a.EAN IS NOT NULL AND b.EAN IS NOT NULL AND a.werksnr IS NOT NULL and b.werksnr IS NOT NULL AND a.EAN = b.EAN AND a.werksnr = b.werksnr) OR
(a.lieferant IS NOT NULL AND b.lieferant IS NOT NULL AND a.werksnr IS NOT NULL AND b.werksnr IS NOT NULL AND a.lieferant = b.lieferant AND a.werksnr = b.werksnr) OR
(a.lieferant IS NOT NULL AND b.lieferant IS NOT NULL AND a.EAN IS NOT NULL AND b.EAN IS NOT NULL AND a.lieferant = b.lieferant AND a.EAN = b.EAN);
```

[screenshot](http://s1.directupload.net/file/d/3067/7uu5asw4_png.htm)

Comment: please provide table with some sample data. Also provide your expected output

Comment: I'm really curious - why would you use a VIEW in MySQL (they're not materialized).  As for your question, which values were you expecting to be excluded?  Could the columns values be empty rather than NULL?